# Equivalent table or view of Oracle V_$OSSTAT in POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql, monitoring

I want to fetch the equivalent view of Oracle table V_$OSSTAT in Postgres.

I did the search for **The Statistics Collector**, but not able to get the approx result.

[image]

Comment: https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/monitoring-postgresql-database-system-activities-performance-system-stats-extension

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL does not offer any views that provide information about the operating system.

The main reason for that is that PostgreSQL supports many different operating systems, and that would require specific code for each.

Fortunately, most operating systems provide ways to monitor that, so you don't have to do it with the database.

If you really want, you can write a PL/PerlU or a PL/Python function that provides the information and define a view on top of it.